Is there a way to Protect/Lock a range of cells from being edited in an Excel report that was exported from Report Builder 3.0 (v15.0.19914.0)?
Basically, working on a project automating a scorecard in SQL Report Builder, and the end-user has a requirement to lock a certain section of the scorecard once it is exported to Excel. Can that be done? I know you can set formatting changes to specific cells, but I can't seem to find how to lock a cell for editing.
Any ideas?
I've researched and cannot find any resources. So not sure how popular this question is.

The short answer is no, you can't do this out-of-the-box unfortunately.
